# Get the "nth" occurance of an entry in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of orders from customers. I want to echo the results of all my orders, but when it is a returning customer I want to see if the particular order is their 2nd, 3rd, etc.

For example:

```
|--id--name---date------|
|---1--Eric---01-01-16--|
|---2--Bob----01-02-16--|
|---3--Mary---01-03-16--|
|---4--Bob----01-04-16--|
```

php:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('
    SELECT 
        name, 
        details 
    FROM 
        table 
    ORDER BY 
        date DESC
');
while($echo = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo $echo->name.$echo->details.'<br>';
}
```

result:

```
Bob - Order details *Second purchase
Mary - Order details
Bob - Order details
Eric - Order details
```

Comment: is name a unique field?

Comment: + is it a requirement to have the logic in the query or are you querying all your data so you can do this in your php code?

Comment: date column data type should be date. please check it is string or what ??

Comment: `DISTINCT` & `GROUP BY` will help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following sql query to get the orders with their rank:

```
Select Id, Name, Date,
( 
                CASE Name 
                WHEN @curName 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curName := Name END
              ) + 1 AS rank
from  orders o,  (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curName := '') r
Group BY Name, Date, Id
Order BY Name, date asc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88511/11)